# Detecting if multiple characters are found within group of string vectors

Tags: r

I want to see if the letter in each row of df1 are contained as a group in vec1. Ideally, a third column in df1 would be logical. For example, rows 29 and 34 would be TRUE, while 37 and 38 would be FALSE. I have tried below (df1.new), but output does not look the way I envision.

```
df1 <- structure(list(a = c("Q", "S", "S", "S", "W", "W", "W", "W", 
"W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "A", "N", "Q", "Q", "Q", "Q", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", "W", 
"D", "T", "S", "S"), b = c("M", "H", "R", "H", "C", "F", "I", 
"K", "L", "M", "P", "Q", "R", "V", "Y", "F", "I", "M", "T", "V", 
"W", "Y", "M", "C", "F", "I", "L", "V", "F", "I", "L", "T", "V", 
"Y", "C", "V", "N", "Y")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-38L))

vec1 <- c("AGILV", "CMST", "P", "FWY", "HKR", "DENQ")

df1.new <- df1 %>% mutate(new = paste("[", paste(df1$a, df1$b, sep = "&"), "]", sep = "") %in% vec1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` option could be:

```
df1 %>%
 bind_cols(map_dfc(.x = vec1,
                   ~ df1 %>%
                    transmute(!!.x := str_detect(.x, a) & str_detect(.x, b))) %>%
            transmute(c = rowSums(select(., everything())) >= 1))

   a b     c
1  Q M FALSE
2  S H FALSE
3  S R FALSE
4  S H FALSE
5  W C FALSE
6  W F  TRUE
7  W I FALSE
8  W K FALSE
9  W L FALSE
10 W M FALSE
11 W P FALSE
12 W Q FALSE
13 W R FALSE
14 W V FALSE
15 W Y  TRUE
16 N F FALSE
17 N I FALSE
18 N M FALSE
19 N T FALSE
20 N V FALSE
21 N W FALSE
22 N Y FALSE
23 A M FALSE
24 N C FALSE
25 Q F FALSE
26 Q I FALSE
27 Q L FALSE
28 Q V FALSE
29 W F  TRUE
30 W I FALSE
31 W L FALSE
32 W T FALSE
33 W V FALSE
34 W Y  TRUE
35 D C FALSE
36 T V FALSE
37 S N FALSE
38 S Y FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R`

```
df1$c <-  Reduce(`|`, lapply(vec1, function(x) {
       x1 <- strsplit(x, "")[[1]]
       df1$a %in% x1 & df1$b %in% x1}))
```